# PHP match 2 selected table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, view

I've to select 2 table from mysql. After select the data from query and I would to to match for this 2 table. Code is in below

```
echo "<table>";

foreach($tableA as $tableA){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $tableA['ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $tableA['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $tableA['Date'] . "</td>";

    // Start a new table for description    
    echo "<td><table>"; 
    foreach($tableB as $tableB){                    
        if ($tableA['ID'] = $tableB['ID']){
            echo "<td>" . $tableB['Item'] . "</td>";
        }
        else {
            // do nothing
        }
    }               
    echo "</table></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Table A

```
ID  Name    Date
1   Test 1  1/01/2014
2   Test 2  2/01/2014
3   Test 3  3/01/2014
4   Test 4  4/01/2014
5   Test 5  5/01/2014
```

Table B

```
ID  Item
1   Tomato
1   Orange
2   Apple
2   Watermelon
3   Honeydrew
4   Pineapple
4   Durian
5   Grape
```

From this 2 table A and B, I select from query, but from the PHP codeigniter View, how can match this 2 table to below sample table? Please help.
Join the data:

```
ID  Name    Date        Item
1   Test 1  1/01/2014   Tomato
                        Orange
2   Test 2  2/01/2014   Apple
                        Watermelon
3   Test 3  3/01/2014   Honeydrew
4   Test 4  4/01/2014   Pineapple
                        Durian
5   Test 5  5/01/2014   Grape
```

Answer (score 1):

Matching the data in PHP after it is pulled from separate queries is very sloppy and generally doesnt work well. Just join them in your MySQL query and the data will come out already matched up.

Example:

```
$query = "SELECT a.id, a.name, a.date, b.item 
          FROM tableA a 
          LEFT JOIN tableB b
          ON a.id = b.id 
          WHERE {your selection criteria here}
          ORDER BY a.name ASC, a.date ASC"
```

Then loop through it

```
$result_set = mysql_query($query,$connection);

echo "<table>";
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set)) {
    echo "<tr>" . "<td>{$result['id']}</td>" . "<td>{$result['name']}</td>" . "<td>{$result['date']}</td>" . "<td>{$result['item']}</td>" . "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

clean and easy.

EDIT: New code below regarding your comment

```
$result_set = mysql_query($query,$connection);
$previousName = "";
$previousDate = "";

echo "<table>";
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set)) {
    $currentName = $result['name']; $currentDate = $result['date'];

    if (($currentName == $previousName && $currentDate == $previousDate) || $previousName = "") {
        $id = $result['id']; $name = $result['name']; $date = $result['date']; $item .= ", ".$result['item'];
    } else {
        echo "<tr>" . "<td>{$id}</td>" . "<td>{$name}</td>" . "<td>{$date}</td>" . "<td>{$item}</td>" . "</tr>";
        $id = $result['id']; $name = $result['name']; $date = $result['date']; $item = $result['item'];
    }  

    $previousName = $result['name']; $previousDate = $result['date'];
}
echo "<tr>" . "<td>{$id}</td>" . "<td>{$name}</td>" . "<td>{$date}</td>" . "<td>{$item}</td>" . "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: thanks for your code.. I does this code before.. But it will display duplicate name if item is more than 1.. like 1. Test 1  1/01/2014   Tomato 2. Test 1 1/01/2014 Orange

Comment: What you mentioned in your comment is something that is best handled through PHP as opposed to MySQL. See my edited response above for an example of how to do what you are asking.

Comment: if let's say want to merge 2 row for Test 1.. what is the code? thanks for advise..

Answer (score 0):

Below may satisfy you.

```
echo "<table>";

foreach($tableA as $rowA){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $rowA['ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rowA['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rowA['Date'] . "</td>";

    // Start a new table for description    
    echo "<td><table>"; 
    foreach($tableB as $rowB){    
        if ($rowA['ID'] == $rowB['ID']){
            echo "<tr>" . $rowB['Item'] . "</tr>";
        }   
        else {
            // do nothing
        }   
    }        
    echo "</table></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```